# Short story where a woman's lover is an angel in disguise

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This was a short story about a (male) angel who visited a maiden. Every night he is intimate with her, but refuses to show his face to her. He tells her that if she really loves him, she would not insist on seeing him.

When she cannot resist any longer she lit a candle and saw his beautiful being, and he flew away  saying his goodbye (as in '*you don't love me'*) and is never seen again.

Comment: Should _"if he really loves her"_ be _"if she really loves him"_?

Comment: @JohnRennie - That seems a fairly obvious typo. Fixed.

Comment: Sounds a bit like "[Cupid and Psyche](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cupid_and_Psyche)".